# How do I make gpg-agent forget my passphrase automatically?

Tags: gpg, thunderbird, gpg-agent

I'm using Thunderbird with enigmail and gpg. From thunderbird/enigmail, I can't make the gpg-agent forget my passphrase, enigmail tells me I'm using gpg-agent for passphrase management so enigmail can't forget my passphrase.

Is there a way to make gpg-agent forget my passphrase periodically? To be honest, I only skimmed the manpage but it looked like there was nothingin there.

Comment: `man gpg-agent | less -p default-cache`...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`--default-cache-ttl` option](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html) to set how long to keep an entry around:

```
eval $(gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 300)
```

will cache for five minutes. You can also set this in your `gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
default-cache-ttl 300
```

The default is ten minutes (600 seconds). These timeouts will be reset when you use the key. `max-cache-ttl` sets the upper limit before reentering the passphrase.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by this: "these timesout will be reset when you use the key". Do you mean if we run any gpg command it will auto reset ?

Comment: @MaXi32 **y**es.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make `gpg-agent` forget your passphrase on demand (for instance, when your screensaver activates) you can send it a `SIGHUP`:

```bash
killall -s HUP gpg-agent
```

That'll generate a log file entry like this:

> 2014-09-19 16:14:22 gpg-agent[1100] SIGHUP received - re-reading configuration and flushing cache

Answer (score 1):

You can just kill it. This is the canonical way to kill gpg-agent:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Comment: Sounds like that would do more than make it forget one passphrase!?!

Comment: True, but it's likely OP has only one passphrase. None of the solutions offered here allow you to forget just one passphrase. There should be a way to do that using `gpg-connect-agent` however (the `CLEAR_PASSPHRASE` command).